# how do you access a widget that is in a different class in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

How can I access the conditions value that is located inside my `CurrentWeather` widget from Python in my `AddLocationForm`? I want to edit the conditions value from my `AddLocationForm` instead of doing it in `CurrentWeather`. This is my code, so far:

**Python:**

```
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
import json
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.factory import Factory

Window.clearcolor = (0.45, 0.3, 1, 0.5)

class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):
    search_input = ObjectProperty()
    search_results = ObjectProperty()
    currentWeather = ObjectProperty()

    def search_location(self):
        search_template = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=f8020ca79e2de4c1dd5a125c3f22fa18"
        search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
        request = UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location)

    def found_location(self, request, data):
        data = json.loads(data.decode()) if not isinstance(data, dict) else data
        weather = "%s" %(data["weather"][0]["description"])
        root.WeatherRoot.CurrentWeather.conditions = weather #Problem is here

class LocationButton(ListItemButton):
    pass

class WeatherApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global root
        root = self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

**Kv:**

```
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import main main

WeatherRoot:

<WeatherRoot>:
    AddLocationForm

<AddLocationForm>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    search_input: search_box 
    search_results: search_results_list
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        TextInput:
            id: search_box 
            size_hint_x: 50
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: "Search"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.search_location()
            background_color: (1, 0.5, 0.656, 1)

<CurrentWeather@BoxLayout>:
    id: current_weather
    currentWeather: current_weather
    location: "" 
    conditions: ""
    temp: None
    temp_min: None
    temp_max: None

    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: root.location
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.435, "y": 1}
        font_size: '40dp'       
        size_hint_y: None
        size_hint_x: None
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        Label:
            id: curCon
            text: root.conditions
```

Comment: Would you care to make a minimal example of this? See this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is that better? I was at school, so that is what took me so long to respond.

Answer (score 1):

**Tree:**

```
WeatherRoot:           # root widget

<WeatherRoot>:         # root widget class
    AddLocationForm    # root widget's child
```

Therefore you'll first access your [`App`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords)'s instance with `app`. The instance *after* the build method has a [`root`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.root) [property](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/app.py#L600), which is just an instance of the root widget stored. That's why `global root` is useless in larger code because of e.g. collisions, confusion with some other name, etc while accessible easier in a pretty way.

To access a class dynamically created in kv from python or kv you need to use the widget tree (to get to an already existing instance):

```
app.root.children[0]...
```

or [`Factory`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.factory.html) to *create* an instance of the widget e.g. if you'd like to create a new one after some condition is evaluated.

**But!**

You've misunderstood how the dynamic classes work in kv - the `<Name@Widget>:` is just a **declaration**, not an instance. Like a template. To actually work with it you have to *put* it somewhere, for example:

python:

```
cw = Factory.CurrentWeather()
somewhere.add_widget(cw)
```

kv:

```
WeatherRoot:
    CurrentWeather:  # here

<WeatherRoot>:
    AddLocationForm:
        CurrentWeather:  # or here
```

If you choose to add it in python, you can easily use some variable to store an instance and still be able to access it later through widget tree. On the other hand, when added in kv, you don't have an access to `__init__` and you can't really store an instance into a variable without sillyish hacks like this:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<Blob@Button>:

BoxLayout:
    Button:
        on_release: self.new = Factory.Blob(); self.parent.add_widget(self.new)
```

Therefore to access it you have to first create an instance of it and either store the instance, or go trough the widget tree.